# FFmpeg : why we need to create temp files during conversion

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I have been studying about ffmpeg, its properties and its usage. I have started using a pre-made PHP based script which creates temp files during conversion. I am trying to figure out what it actually does in this given command. Why is this command creating temp files during conversion and what is the purpose of it?

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/conversion_queue/15270581986ece98.mp4 -f mp4  -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -r 23.97598565277  -maxrate 320000 -g 60 -crf 29 -profile:v baseline  -s 426x240 -aspect 1.77  -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 320k -ar 44100  /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/videos/2018/05/23/15270581986ece98/15270581986ece98-240.mp4 2> /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/temp/1527058199834e4.tmp
```

Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg emits its logging messages on stderr.

`2> /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/temp/1527058199834e4.tmp` captures that to the file specified.

If the conversion is successful (exit code 0), you can delete that file. If not, inspect it for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks Gyan Actually i am trying ffmpeg not to hang during conversion of large sized videos in this case what about using this command?
`/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/conversion_queue/15270581986ece98.mp4 -f mp4  -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast -r 23.97598565277  -maxrate 320000 -g 60 -crf 29 -profile:v baseline  -s 426x240 -aspect 1.77  -acodec libfdk_aac -ab 320k -ar 44100  /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/videos/2018/05/23/15270581986ece98/15270581986ece98-240.mp4 </dev/null >/dev/null 2> /var/www/html/conversion_server/files/temp/ffmpeg.log &`

Comment: Actually what i am trying to do is not to block std pipe during conversion which causes hanging **ffmpeg**

Comment: Then add `-nostdin`

Comment: Ok Gyan Thanks for your help i am accepting this answer.I heard about using -nostdin and you just confirmed it.